# Determine the parity of a number using only logical operators

Tags: c, logical-operators

I am a little bit confused while I'm trying to determine if a number is even / uneven using only logical operators (||, &&).

I'm used to:

```
if (x%2)
   printf("Number is even");
else
   printf("Number is not even");
```

Is there any algorithm that determinates the parity of a number ? If there is, can you give me some documentation ?

Best regards,
Duluman Edi

Comment: *logical* OR and AND, not bitwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you do shifting first? You can accomplish the same "bit" logic with the logical operators if you use just 1 bit, so for example:

```
int num = 0x14; // 0000 0000 0001 0100
unsigned short shift_num = num << 15; // 0000 0000 0000 0000

if(shift_num && 1)
    printf("it's odd\n");
else
    printf("it's even\n");
```

So anything non-0 `&& 1` gives you 1, in this case we shiffted off all but the lowest bit, if it's even (as above) it leaves you with 0 and `0 && 1` is false so `"it's even"` is printed. If we use an odd number:

```
int num = 0x15; // 0000 0000 0001 0101
unsigned short shift_num = num << 15; // 1000 0000 0000 0000
```

Now there's a non-0 number there with the 1 so we'll get `"it's odd"`

Comment: Interesting solution, +1 (although, to make sure you are portably shifting enough for all the range of `int` you should do some `sizeof`/`CHAR_BITS` trickery).

Answer (score 4):

It's impossible using only the logical operators `&&` and `||`.

In any expression involving only `&&` and `||`, you can replace the value `0x01` (which is odd) with `0x10` (which is even), and the result will be the same because both values are logically "true" as far as the logical operators are concerned. Hence, the expression does not discriminate between the two.

If you need to prove it formally, you can do it by strong induction using the fact that any expression involving only those two operators, and which contains `n` operators in total, is necessarily equivalent to an expression of form either `(A) && (B)` or `(A) || (B)`, where `A` and `B` are expressions involving only those two operators and which contain fewer than `n` operators in total. Proving the base case with `n == 1` is simple.

Comment: Thats weird, the lecturer asked us to solve this problem using only logical operators, which makes me believe it's possible. But still, it may be a misspell in his exercises pack.

Comment: @edduvs: it's possible that the lecturer thinks that the bitwise operators are called logical operators. But otherwise I think you're right, it must be a typo of one word for the other.

Answer (score 2):

For an integer you can use the and operator `x & 1` to test for bit 0 value, that is 0 for even and 1 for odd.

Comment: OP said `||` and `&&`, not `|` and `&`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the *bitwise* operators `&` and `|` (since with their logical, short-circuiting counterparts there's no solution):

```
if(x&1)
    puts("odd");
else
    puts("even");
```

(and any decent compiler will automatically emit code for `x&1` when seeing `x%2`)

this works because `&1` extracts the least significant bit of `x`, which is `1` for odd numbers and `0` or even numbers.

Comment: OP said `||` and `&&`, not `|` and `&`

Comment: I'm not allowed to use bitwise operators, just logical.

Comment: @Mike: Occam's razor... is it more likely that he was given a "normal" task but confused the logical operators with their bitwise counterparts or that he was asked a completely impossible exercise?

Comment: True, which is why I left a comment for clarification from @edduvs. In the comments here, the instance is to use "logical" operators, my assumption (below answer) is that the lecturer wanted them to think of another possibility such as shifting off the bits then applying logic operators. But yes, without us being there we're both making assumptions.

Comment: I guess I was confused about the instance of using logical operators, but the shifting bits method is good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

Logical `||` and `&&` *always* yields `true` or `false` value means `1` or `0`.

I think you are confused among `||` `&&` and `&` `|` the later ones are bitwise operators and using bitwise you can find the even and odd

```
if(n & 1)
  printf("odd");
else
  printf("even");
```

Comment: You have them mixed up. If (n & 1) , it should be odd.